# Any issues with distributing an iOS app thru both an Enterprise and the App Store?

Tags: ios, ios7, app-store, enterprise

I've built an application that my company owns the code to.

One company wants a slightly modified version of this app (branding mostly) to distribute internally (using https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/).

I'm also going to sell it thru the ordinary App Store.

Would I run into any issues here? I can't find any information regarding that this somehow wouldn't be allowed, but I don't want to shoot myself in the foot here either...

Any insight out there?

Thanks!

/J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer **NO**.

As far as Apple would see it - they would be two completely different applications. Each one would have a different App ID and a different provisioning profile.

You will however have to purchase an [Apple Enterprise Developer license](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) if you want to distribute through the Enterprise program.

[Here is a link to some commonly asked questions about the Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html)

If you have anymore questions just ask.

Answer (score 1):

There's no conflict here. The only thing is that you'll need different provisioning profiles for each build and you'll need an enterprise developer account to create the enterprise build. Other than that, there aren't any issues.